# How to exactly simulate new T[n] with an allocator?

Tags: c++, initialization, allocator

The expression `new T[n]` *may or may not* initialize each object in the array, depending on what `T` is.

How do I replicate this initialization behavior using an `allocator`?

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    Foo() : x(1)
        { }
};

Foo *p = new Foo[1];
assert(p[0].x == 1);
```

Comment: `operator new[]` itself doesn't initialize anything. Do I misunderstand your question? It just returns the memory, and the compiler does initializations as necessary.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: `struct Foo { int x; Foo() : x(1) { } }; Foo *p = new Foo[1]; assert(p[0].x == 1);` (Edit: Oh, I see what you mean now. Is my edit clear?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++03, the allocator interface only knows one way to initialize objects, and that's to copy from another object. C++11 has more.

You're asking for default initialization, which means (approximately), "either do nothing or call the default constructor". The allocator interface cannot do the latter in C++03.

I suppose you could write something like:

```
T *ra = allocator.allocate(1);
if (!is_pod<T>::value) {
    // in C++03
    allocator.construct(ra, T());
    // in C++11
    allocator.construct(ra);
}
```

That `is_pod` test might be wrong, though. Check the standard for exactly what conditions default initialization does nothing. Obviously `is_pod` doesn't exist in C++03, but I vaguely recall that Boost has something of the kind that works on most implementations.

I think that you're fighting the design here. The allocator interface was designed for use by containers. Containers were designed not to contain uninitialized elements, so they have no use for default initialization.

Comment: In C++11, allocators have emplacing `construct`s that take any number of arguments, including none.

Comment: @KerrekSB: drat, I'd remembered that and was updating, but you're too fast.