# Efficiently populate vector of known size

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I want to create a `std::vector<int>` of a known size and immediately fill it with some generated values. Is there a way to do this without either (1) first zero-filling the vector to the desired size or (2) using `reserve` then `push_back` on every element?

For example, to fill the vector with values 0 though `size-1`:

```
// method 1
vector<int> fill_resize(int s) {
  vector<int> v(s);
  for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
    v[i] = i;
  }
  return v;
}

// method 2
vector<int> fill_push_back(int s) {
  vector<int> v;
  v.reserve(s);
  for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
    v.push_back(i);
  }
  return v;
}
```

Method (1) wastes time by redundantly zero filling, and method (2) needs the machinery of `push_back` on every insert, which in practice compiles poorly.

Before someone jumps in and says "compilers are smart, they'll optimize this for you!" - [check out the generated assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/vGkY0L) on cutting edge compilers at `-O2`. It is pretty awful, with the `push_back` variant taking the cake in awfulness<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>Interestingly enough, the awful `push_back` version still wins for very large vectors, because there you are limited mostly by memory bandwidth, and the zero-then-fill approach of method 1 takes 2x the bandwidth. The `push_back` approach at least only loops over the values once, but using a slow loop.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138407/discussion-on-question-by-beeonrope-efficiently-populate-vector-of-known-size).

Answer (score 3):

You could:

- Create your own vector type.
- Use unique_ptr as described here (assuming you don't need to resize your array): https://stackoverflow.com/a/24852984/673679
- Fill your vector with a proxy integer type, with an empty constructor, similar to what's described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15220853/673679

Comment: Thanks. I especially like the second idea since it is pretty lightweight and requires no new implementation.